# Gradle dependency substitution with project configuration

Tags: gradle, dependencies

I'm trying to replace all `-SNAPSHOT` dependencies with a local sub-project. it works fine, but I have an issue: I can't define the project configuration that I want to use (it takes `default`, which extends `runtime`, and I don't want that):

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.dependencySubstitution {
        all { dependency ->
            if (!dependency.requested.version.endsWith('SNAPSHOT'))
                return
            def isRootProject = rootProject.name.equals(dependency.requested.module)
            def matching = rootProject.subprojects.find {
                it.name.equals(dependency.requested.module)
            }
            if (isRootProject)
                dependency.useTarget rootProject
            else if (matching)
                // The specified syntax with path: and configuration: does not work. How can I do ?
                dependency.useTarget project(path: ":" + dependency.requested.module, configuration: 'compile')
            else
                println 'Keep SNAPSHOT: ' + dependency.requested.module;
        }
    }
}
```

I know why it doesn't work, the documentation is pretty clear: https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/DependencySubstitutions.html#project%28java.lang.String%29 it does not support a configuration name.

Is there a known workaround for this limitation ?

Answer (score 0):

In your **settings.gradle** file you could do something along those lines:

```
def myDeps = ['my-dependency', 'my-dependency-2']
for (String projectName : myDeps) {
  if (new File(rootDir, '../' + projectName).exists()) {
    def path = '../' + projectName
    def mod  = 'my.company:' + projectName
    System.out.println("Adding composite build for project: " + projectName + " using path: " + path + " replacing module: " + mod);
    includeBuild(path) {
      dependencySubstitution {
        substitute module(mod) with project(':')
      }
    }
   } else {
     System.out.println("Skipping composite build for project: " + projectName);
   }
}
```

If you are fancy, you can do as we do and not use a static list of dependencies. Instead, you can auto-discover the present projects. This requires your company following a static template of configuration in each dependency because you have to parse the files manually.